Measurement frequency for indicated coil inductance
This choke inductor has an inductance of 100 µH according to the website.

I know, however, that inductance varies with frequency (due to parasitics). So, I was wondering at which frequency was the indicated inductance (100 µH) measured and if there was any standard that fixes this frequency?
Update:
Following the comment of @tobalt, saying that the inductance should be constant over a wide frequency range, I measured series inductance (Ls) of this relay with an LCR meter and indeed its value was rather constant in the range [100, 100k] Hz.
To confirm this behavior, I have measured series resistance (Rs) and series inductance (Ls) of the coil of a 24VDC relay as a function of frequency (figure below).

In contrast to the previous inductor, the inductance of the relay coil is only constant in the range [1, 10] Hz, which is a very small range.
I also noticed that the datasheet of this relay doesn't have any indication on inductance. It only gives an indication of \$R_s = 3390 \pm 10\% \Omega\$, which is consistent with the (very near) DC value I found (\$3245 \Omega\$).
So, I'm not sure which value should I use to characterize this relay. In particular, if I want to know the time constant (\$\tau = L_s/R_s\$), then which \$L_s\$ value should I use?
Any help is appreciated.

Have you checked the datasheet?

The inductance is pretty constant over a wide frequency range for commercial inductors up until close to the self resonance frequency. The inductance value is measured in this constant-inductance range, usually at an order of magnitude below the self resonance frequency or lower.

@winny, I couldn't find a reference to check the datasheet. No info on the website.

EE 101, don't buy components without datasheets.

@tobalt, I guess you're right! I measured Ls with an LCR meter and I got the following values (f [Hz], Ls [µH]) : (100, 104), (1k, 105), (10k, 101.5), (100k, 96.85).
I always thought the variation of Ls with frequency would be more significant!

@tobalt, I measured another relay and the results were a bit different then those of the first relay. Please see the update.

@winny, I have used a relay with a datasheet this time. I'd appreciate it if you can check the update I made.

A relay is not designed to be a good inductor, it's designed to be a relay. It just happens to have some inductance, which blows up your driver if you don't allow for it.

@Neil_UK, So, if I understood correctly, you're basically saying that if I had an inductor (not just the coil of a relay), then the statement that its inductance stays constant over a wide range of frequencies would hold true. And it would be this constant value that I need to use to compute the time constant $\tau$.

In fact the relay will measure two different values [of impedance curves], depending on if it's open or closed as well! If you'd like to know the physical reason for this, we could explain (edit your question to ask).

@TimWilliams, Actually, I got myself into a rabbit hole by measuring a relay coil instead of an inductor. Originally, I was only interested in inductors. In particular, knowing which value of Ls (from all the values as a function of frequency) to use to get the rise-time.

Oddly, your inductance measurements show a trend of lower inductance at higher frequencies. The usual trend is increasing inductance as frequency approaches self-resonant-frequency (SRF). Above SRF, most inductors become capacitive.

So, I was wondering at which frequency was the indicated inductance
(100 µH) measured and if there was any standard that fixes this
frequency?

There is no standard frequency for measuring inductors. A manufacturer likely provides specifications related to its intended application. Since core material on which an inductor is wound varies greatly, and wire diameter, length varies greatly, the useful frequency range also varies. A 100nH inductor might be used at 100 MHz, while a 100uH inductor might be used at 1 MHz.

A 100uH inductor intended for energy transfer in a DC-DC switching power supply might carefully specify resistance, or data related to core saturation, or maximum temperature.
A 100uH inductor intended for high-pass or low-pass filtering might concentrate on self-resonant frequency, and simply specify maximum DC current that causes inductor tolerance to be violated.
A 100uH inductor intended for an oscillator circuit where frequency is critical might concentrate on temperature effects, and inductor quality factor (Q).

A manufacturer specifies three 100uH inductors in different ways:
RLB0812-101KL 100uh ± 10 %:

Q=45 at 0.796 MHz
SRF=4.20 MHz
R(DC)= 0.60 ohms
I(max)= 320 ma. (temperature rises by 20C) 

RLB1014-101KL 100uh ± 10 %:

Q=45 at 796 kHz
SRF=3.20 MHz
R(DC)=0.85 ohms
I(RMS)=0.78 A (where temperature rises by 40C)
I(saturation)=2A (where inductance drops 10%)


78F101J-RC:

100uh ±5 % at 25 degrees C.
Q=60 measured at 2.5 MHz
SRF = 5.50 MHz
R(DC)= 4.10 ohms
I(max)= 165mA

You wouldn't likely use this last one for energy transfer in a DC-DC switcher, but might use it in a low-pass filter, or oscillator circuit.

I wouldn't say it's odd at all -- consider the construction of a relay, coil and parts, and what might happen to inductance at various frequencies.

@TimWilliams OP's photo of a choke inductor certainly differs from a relay coil.

Read more closely -- that was a visual example; the plot is of a completely different item. A strange choice, I know.

The "rise of inductance" below the SRF is likely an artifact of attributing the measured impedance/reactance to a wrong equivalent circuit. What happens at higher frequencies, is that the turns are progressively shorted which reduces inductance.
